# Get TermAttribute in TokenStream Lucene.Net

Tags: .net, lucene.net

I use Lucene.NET3.0.3
how to get TermAttribute.I try my best but i can't get it

here source:

```
    Analyzer analyzer = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Snowball.SnowballAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "English",stopword);

    TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.TokenStream("English", new StringReader("How to get TermAttribute"));

    while (tokenStream.IncrementToken())
    {
         ???How to get TermAttribute

    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var termAttr = tokenStream.GetAttribute<Lucene.Net.Analysis.Tokenattributes.ITermAttribute>();

while(tokenStream.IncrementToken())
{
    string term = termAttr.Term;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In [Apache Lucene.Net 4.8](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet) you can use this C# code: *(.NET Core 2+)* where `term = termAttr.ToString()` contains **Token** as `string`. Complete method: `PrintTokens(Analyzer analyzer, string fieldName, string text)` you can get at *GitHub* [msigut/LuceneNet48Demo](https://github.com/msigut/LuceneNet48Demo/blob/master/src/LuceneNet48Demo/Search/MySearch.cs).

```cs
    var tokenStream = analyzer.GetTokenStream(fieldName, textToAnalyze);
    var termAttr = tokenStream.GetAttribute<ICharTermAttribute>();

    tokenStream.Reset();

    while (tokenStream.IncrementToken())
    {
        string term = termAttr.ToString();
    }
```